# Google Sheets query to get sum of two columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get sum of two columns using Query function and am getting perfect result when all the two columns have value, however, if any of the column is not having a value than the result will be blank. In such a case I want to reflect the value of the second column having data. Check the below image:

[image]

Formula used =QUERY(A2:C,"select A,B+C label B+C ''",0)

Sharing the link of the sheet too for reference.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TID_7m6MTNviLkU0dlPoCDyA8Uv9Iann2WtCYL9CJQo/edit#gid=0

Any help on above will be appreciated.
I had also searched community for similar issue but not found the exact match.

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=QUERY({A2:A,INDEX(IF(B2:C="",0,B2:C))},"select Col1,Col2+Col3 where Col1 is not null label Col2+Col3 ''")
```

- Here `IF(B2:C="",0,B2:C)` will convert null cells to zero `0` values.

[image]

Comment: @ Harum24hr ... thanks for super quick and perfect solution....

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX({A2:A4, B2:B4+C2:C4})
```